# Fastest solution to get the positions of the bits

Tags: c, bit

I would like to know the position of the bits where it is set, so far [I wrote the following code](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php):

```
unsigned long a = 0x0102C121;
int pos = 0;
printf("%x\r\n", a);
while(a)
{       
    if(a & 0x1)
        //Handling the position, right now just printing the position
        printf("Position:%d\r\n", pos);

    a >>= 1;
    ++pos;        
}
printf("Loop number:%d\r\n", pos);
```

I am wondering if there are better/faster solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling `printf` in the loop, then any faster bit-twiddling will be swamped by the complexity of output functions.

If you want to know what bits are set, then there are other ways, but it strongly depends what the rest of the algorithm is doing with the information.

It isn't worth optimising 'doing something for each bit set' but there are optimisations for counting the number of bits set or finding the index of the bit set if only one is set in the [bit twiddling hacks archive](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: There is an array which are pointing different function and I would like to call this functions according of the bits.

Comment: @run then it's likely that the bit test operation what you have is probably about as fast as anything. If the bits tend to be sparse, it may be worth testing `a&0xff` and skipping 8 bits at once, but it depends on the values of `a` in your system.

Answer (score 2):

You could unroll your while loop to get rid of a cycle overhead and bit shifting and incrementation like this:

```
unsigned long a = 0x0102C121;
int pos = 0;
printf("%x\r\n", a);

if(a & 0x1) printf("Position:%d\r\n", 0);
if(a & 0x2) printf("Position:%d\r\n", 1);
if(a & 0x4) printf("Position:%d\r\n", 2);
...
if(a & 0x80000000) printf("Position:%d\r\n", 31);
```

It looks ugly but it will be faster, but it could trash your instruction cache if you had too much code for processing each of your bit position.

Comment: If `long` is 64 bits, that might be a bit too much. But the OP could unroll *parts* of the loop. E.g. do eight bits at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more method to fasten the execution for finding the number of bits . I always feel we will be wasting lot of time in checking the each bit whether it is set or not .

Instead of checkign each bit , we can check whole nibble ( Or byte)  once to see if any of the bit is set in that nibble( Or byte) . If the check is true then we might need to check in normal way to get the position .

In this way we would be eliminating un-necessary checks .

Sample code which does this is

while(temp)
  {

```
if (! ((char)temp & 0xff ) ) 

 /*Checks bitwise if any of the bits are set in 8 bits ..*/

 temp = temp >> 8;

 else        /*Our bit check logic */
```

}